# Use Okta to authenticate and redirect to another page in different domain

Tags: angular, okta

I have a login page hosted in domain http://example1.com. In this page, I am using okta log-in widget (https://developer.okta.com/code/javascript/okta_sign-in_widget/) to authenticate user. After authenticated, based on user profile, I will redirect them to different dashboards (http://example2.com or http://example3.com).

Those dashboard are made with Angular and using Okta Auth Js SDK.

My current approach is using getWithRedirect (https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-js#tokengetwithredirectoptions) to redirect to the dashboard after user logged in. However, in Angular callback page, it returns error **AuthSdkError: Unable to retrieve OAuth redirect params cookie**.

Here is my code. Do you guys have experience in solving this? Please help.

```
oktaSignIn.authClient.token.getWithRedirect({
redirectUri: "http://localhost:4200/login/callback",
responseType: ["token", "id_token"],
state: data.state, // will be URI encoded
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Oauth is SP Initiated, after a User is successfully Authenticated on example.com, just do a javascript redirect to example2 or example 3.

When the User is lands example2 or example3, just generate the /Authorize request against Okta. *SP Initiated means the application with generate the request for authentication*.

It will look something like this:

`https://companyx.okta.com/oauth2/v1/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=vZV6Cp8rn5lxrN9aZ688&redirect_uri=https://oktaproxy.com/oidc&scope=openid%20profile&state=af0ifjsldkj&nonce=n-0S6_WzA2Mj`

If you send the request above w/ the parameter **prompt=none**, that will tell Okta that if the User is not Authenticated forward the error (The error saying the User is not Authenticated back to example2 or example3) In that case, you send the User back to example1 to perform an Authentication.

The angular SDK is really designed for SPA apps, but since your apps are running on different servers, don't strictly lock yourself into that Angular SDK. It might be easier to just log into Okta, then start the work on Example2 and Example3. Once that is working, it's very easy with the login widget to create a simple page that does Authentication, after successful Authentication, just redirect the User to example2 or example3.